# PHP explain the pipe in error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Tags: php, pipe

Please could someone confirm how many parameters are being sent to error_reporting() in the code: error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

My assumption is that there is only one parameter which is the result of a bit wise OR of the two constants in the brackets.

I'd just like to be sure that this is not an alternative way to send multiple parameters to a function (i.e. alternative to using ,).  Or it's not doing something funky like sending a array containing both constants as a single parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: mario - thanks for that link but this is not a duplicate of a question in there.  Your link explains bit wise OR, which I already understood.  My question is there another significance of the pipe symbol in this context in PHP.  Looking at others answers there is not.  Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your first assumption; it's a bitwise OR between `E_ALL` and `E_STRICT`. When I run the following code:

```
echo 'E_ALL: ' . decbin(E_ALL) . '<br>';
echo 'E_STRICT: ' . decbin(E_STRICT) . '<br>';
```

I get this:

```
E_ALL: 111011111111111
E_STRICT: 100000000000
```

Which results in

```
111111111111111
```

When bitwise ORed.

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption is that there is only one parameter which is the result
>   of a bit wise OR of the two constants in the brackets.

Correct

> I'd just like to be sure that this is not an alternative way to send
>   multiple parameters to a function (i.e. alternative to using ,).

Not that I know of :-)